# Как вместе с маркером добавить и подпись для yandex maps?

Tags: яндекс-карты

поставил карту на сайт через API + поставил маркер. Как рядом с маркером поставить такую надпись?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.694843, 37.435023], {
    balloonContent: 'цвет <strong>носика Гены</strong>',
    iconCaption: 'Очень длиннный, но невероятно интересный текст'
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Источник: [API Карт](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark)